# Get search result exported to CSV - django

Tags: django, search, export-to-csv

I have a search functionality where I also provide the user to export the search result as csv. My search function works fine. but, the export function is unable to collect the search result done by the user. I can understand the reason behind this problem but unable to find a way to deal with it. (Usage of Global variable might be helpful, but I don't want to use it) 
My search query function:

```
def search_query(request):
    result = publication.objects.all()
    query = request.GET.get("query")
    if query:
        result = result.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) 
            Q(timeStamp__icontains=query)
        ).distinct()
    user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET, queryset=result)

    return user_filter
```

My Search function:

```
def search(request):
    title = "Advanced Search"
    user_filter = search_query(request)
    context = {
        'title': title,
        'filter': user_filter,
    }
    return render(request, "search.html", context)
```

My export function:

```
def export_search_csv(request):
    data = search_query(request)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename=publications.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Title', 'Published On'])
    for item in data.qs:
        writer.writerow([item.title, item.timeStamp.strftime("%b-%Y")])
    return response
```

**UPD:**

html (export portion):

```
<p>
    <h5>
    <a href="{% url 'publication:export_search_csv' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}" class="btn btn-default" style="width: 150px; role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save">  </span> Export to CSV</a>      
    </h5>
  </p>
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('publications.urls', namespace='publication')),
    ]
```

publications/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^export/csv/$', views.export_search_csv, name='export_search_csv'),
]
```

Please help.

**Traceback** (most recent call last):

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 217, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 215, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py", line 107, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/response.py", line 84, in rendered_content
    content = template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/backends/django.py", line 66, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 207, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 177, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 199, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 72, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 990, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 458, in render
    url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/urls/base.py", line 91, in reverse
    return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.11-py2.7.egg/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 497, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'export_search_csv' not found. 'export_search_csv' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using  export to csv link inside your template you can try to specify  current get parameters with this link, something like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'export_search_csv' %}?{{ request.GET.urlencode }}">export to csv</a>
```

This will allow to pass current filter arguments to export view.

Comment: Tried. gives error "Reverse for 'export_search_csv' not found. 'export_search_csv' is not a valid view function or pattern name." Do I need to make any changes to my functions.

Comment: @surajitM did you link view with url? add your urls.py and search.html code.

Comment: @surajitM check what is your app name. In url.py you are using `publications` but you said app urls is inside folder `publication` not `publications`. Probably this is the reason. Can you post full error message?

Comment: Got it working. There was a comment in my html which was causing the error (weird though). Thank you so much @neverwalkaloner